# Работа с файлами пакета, с помощью команд dpkq, apt astra linux

Tags: linux, dpkg, apt, astra-linux

Необходимо получить следующие сведения о пакете: сколько конфигурационных файлов,  утилит пользовательских, утилит для суперпользователя, файлов-библиотек, сколько и какой документации (man, info, doc), какие еще важные файлы есть в пакете. С помощью команды dpkg -L login, вывелись все файлы пакете, дальше с помощью grep получилось отфильтровать, но только по пути например файлы у которых в пути встречается man, doc и это предположительно файлы документации, но вот как точно вывести именно нужные файлы найти не получается.

Comment: А попробуйте сначала определить, что́ вы считаете пользовательской утилитой, конфигурационным файлом и важным файлом, например.

Comment: вот как раз эту информацию пока найти не удалось, а в задании четко не указано.

Comment: у важных файлов из астры должны быть звание и номер противогаза

Comment: Конфигурационные файлы перечисленны в метаданных пакета

Comment: а есть какие-то способы найти их с помощью grep или find, так как точно имена не известны?

Comment: `/var/lib/dpkg/info/имя_пакета.conffiles`

Comment: `apt-file` ищет по имени файла внутри пакета и выдаёт полные пути. Так что можно фильтрануть `conf`, `/usr/lib`, `/usr/bin` и т.д.